# TypeError: this.canvas is undefined (in declared object)

Tags: javascript, object, this

HTML

```
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

JavaScript

```
var objMap = {
htmlID: 'ctx',
canvas: document.getElementById(this.htmlID),
ctx: this.canvas.getContext('2d')};
```

In console the error shows up.
"TypeError: this.canvas is undefined"
I really want to have this in variables in object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do that with direct object. However with an annonymous function you can try building your object.

```
var objMap = new function () {
this.htmlID= 'ctx';
this.canvas= document.getElementById(this.htmlID);
this.ctx= this.canvas.getContext('2d');
};
```

Comment: It will be the same if I do something like this? function Map(){ this.htmlID= 'ctx';
this.canvas= document.getElementById(this.htmlID);
this.ctx= this.canvas.getContext('2d');}  var objMap = new Map();